# Making an image slider with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am completely new to jquery (as of today I just took the code academy course on jquery). I am attempting to make an image slider. I feel like I have working idea but am missing something fundamental. I want it to just run infinitely so I have it set to run continuously as the page is open. Can anyone help me out? I have the opacity of all 5 images set to 0 in the css and am trying to change it with the jquery function I wrote.

I know I can do this with keyframes in css. I am fairly well versed in CSS. I am just tyring to get a grip on javascript and jquery at this point. Take a look:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img = $('.slides');
  for(i = 0; i <= $img.length; i++){
    $img[i].style('opacity', 1);
  };
});
```

```css
/*gallery row*/
  .img-slider-container{
    margin: 10% 10%;
 }
    /*gallery list*/
    .image-list{

    }
    .image-list li{
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .image-list li img{
      display: block;
      width: 15em;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    /* gallery container */
    .img-slider{
      width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<section class="img-slider-container row">
  <div class="col-12 img-slider">
    <ul class="image-list">
      <li><img src="design/images/portfolio-images/one.jpg" class="slides" alt=""/></li>
      <li><img src="design/images/portfolio-images/two.jpg" class="slides" alt=""/></li>
      <li><img src="design/images/portfolio-images/three.jpg" class="slides" id="starting-image" alt=""/></li>
      <li><img src="design/images/portfolio-images/four.jpg" class="slides" alt=""/></li>
      <li><img src="design/images/portfolio-images/five.jpg" class="slides" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think setInterval function is the proper way. There's a youtube tutorial out there. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzVFB3Ba_o Watch this so you can understand how the slider works. There's a lot of way but this one is absolutely excellent.

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval` to run your script infinitely.. And also you have defines `$img` incorrectly it should be `$(img)`. So, try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img = $('.slides');
  setInterval(function(){for(i = 0; i <= $(img).length; i++){
    $(img[i]).css('opacity', 1)}
  },1000);

});
```